# Putting a href click function into a if-else-statement

Tags: jquery, click, href, if-statement

I've got this function

```
$("a[href*=/category/movies/]").click(function() {
so.addVariable('stretching','fill');
so.write('mediaspace');
});
```

that I want to turn into an if...else statement.

How do I target links inside div#header_playlist_categories
and apply an else statement, if links point to other than '/categories/movies/' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to handle all clicks on `a` elements within `div#header_playlist_categories`.  You then want to do one thing if the link's `href` attribute contains `/category/movies/` and another if it does not.  If so, you can do this nicely using [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('#header_playlist_categories').delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // I imagine you always want to disable the default action

    if (this.href.indexOf('/category/movies/') !== -1) {
        so.addVariable('stretching','fill');
        so.write('mediaspace');
    } else {
        // do whatever else you want to do
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'll probably be using this another time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) like this to get the *other* links:

```
$("#header_playlist_categories a:not([href*=/category/movies/])").click(function() {
  //something else
});
```

Or a bit cheaper, check in the loop:

```
$("a").each(function() {
 if(this.href.indexOf("/category/movies/") !== -1) {
   $(this).click(function() {
     so.addVariable('stretching','fill');
     so.write('mediaspace');
   });
 } else {
   $(this).click(function() {
     //something else
   });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should [delegate that event](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/04/event-delegation-with-javascript/) to your `div#header_playlist_categories`.

Inside your callback function, access the "href" attribute of the link that was clicked and branch your handler based on its value.